# How to prove that $\frac{(mn)!}{m!(n!)^m}$ is an integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$\forall m,n\in\mathbb Z$ , $m\ge1$ and $n\ge1$ how to prove that  $$\frac{(mn)!}{m!(n!)^m}$$ is an integer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a nice proof of this using group theory. Which course are you taking?

Comment: @Geoff Robinson:i know concept of group theory.passed one years ago. but i didn't this question in group theory

Comment: There is a nice subgroup of the Symmetric group $S_{mn}$ whose order is $m!(n!)^{m}$. If you can see this, you can apply Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: @Geoff Robinson :excellent idea.i think making this permutation is not hard but why  $$m!(n!)^{m}\le(mn)!$

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: Please share yours with us.

Comment: @Babak S.: I did so below

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note that $\binom{kn}{n}$ must contain a multiple of $k$ therefore $\frac{1}{k}\binom{kn}{n}$ is always an integer.

$$\frac{1}{m!}\cdot\frac{(mn)!}{(n!)^m}=\frac{1}{1}\binom{n}{n}\frac{1}{2}\binom{2n}{n}\cdots\frac{1}{m}\binom{nm}{n}$$

All of these terms are integers!

Comment: This can be derived mechanically by telescopy (see my answer). Out of curiosity, how did you derive it?

Comment: @MathGems Breaking it up: $$\frac{(mn)!}{(n!)^m}=\left(\frac{(1)\cdots (n)}{n!}\right)\left(\frac{(n+1)\cdots (2n)}{n!}\right)\cdots \left(\frac{(n(m-1)+1)\cdots (mn)}{n!}\right)=\binom{n}{n}\binom{2n}{n}\cdots\binom{mn}{n}$$
Then distributing the remain $m!$

Comment: Thanks, as I surmised. But I wondered if there might be other interesting viewpoints.

Comment: Why exactly is $\binom{kn}{n}$ divisible by $k$?

Comment: @CalebJares $\binom{kn}{n}=k\binom{kn-1}{n-1}$

Comment: Interesting. I worked out that those are equal algebraically, but I'm interested to know if there is a combinatorical argument to show they're equal.

Answer (score 16):

We have a group of $mn$ people, and want to divide them into $m$ teams of $n$ people each. Your expression is precisely the number of ways to do it. Since the expression **counts** something, it must always yield an integer.

To count the number of ways to divide the group into $m$ teams, we first count the number of ways to divide them into teams that will wear uniform colours $C_1,C_2,\dots,C_m$.

Line up the people. There are $(mn)!$ ways to do this. Take the first group of $n$, assign it uniforms $C_1$, and so on. This overcounts the number of ways to divide into uniformed teams, since any permutation of the first $n$ people, followed by any permutation of the next $n$, and so on, yields the same subdivision into uniformed teams. It follows that there are $\dfrac{(mn)!}{(n!)^m}$ divisions into uniformed teams.

Any permutation of the uniform colours yields the same division into uniformless teams. So the number of ways to divide our group into teams is  $\dfrac{1}{m!}\dfrac{(mn)!}{(n!)^m}$

Answer (score 10):

OK, since explicit solutions have been given, I will give the group-theoretic approach explicitly. The symmetric group $S_{nm}$ has a subgroup $S_{n} \wr S_{m}.$
This is a semidirect product of a base group $B$ with the symmetric group $S_{m}.$ The base group $B$ is itself a  direct product of $m$ copies of $S_{n},$ and these factors are permuted around by the $S_{m}$ which acts on $B.$  The group $S_{n} \wr S_{m}$ therefore has order $m!(n!)^{m},$ which divides $(mn)!$ by Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: Thanks for doing that. Thanks Geoff. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Divide the expression $(mn)!$ into m groups each group consisting of the nos. $\{(kn+1)(kn+2).....((k+1)n)\}$, here k runs from $0$ to $m-1$

So we have ,$\displaystyle (mn)!=\prod_{k=0}^{m-1}(kn+1)(kn+2).....((k+1)n)$

In each group first $n-1$ nos is divisible by $(n-1)!$ as we have m groups so the total product is divisible by $((n-1)!)^m$ (Using the fact that product of $k$ consecutive nos is divisible by $k!$)

Product of the last nos. of the group is $\displaystyle \prod_{k=0}^{m-1}(k+1)n=m!.n^m$

So the whole product is divisible by $((n-1)!)^m.m!.n^m=m!(n!)^m$

Hence proving the fact that $\displaystyle \frac{(mn)!}{m!(n!)^m}$ is an integer.

Answer (score 4):

Use telescopy: $\rm\:f(0),\ f(k+1)/f(k)\in \Bbb Z\ \Rightarrow\: f(m)\in \Bbb Z\ $ since

$$\rm f(0)\ \ \prod_{k\:=\:0}^{m-1}\ \frac{f(k+1)}{f(k)}\ \ = \ \ \ \color{red}{\rlap{--}f(0)}\frac{\color{green}{\rlap{--}f(1)}}{\color{red}{\rlap{--}f(0)}}\frac{\color{royalblue}{\rlap{--}f(2)}}{\color{green}{\rlap{--}f(1)}}\frac{\phantom{\rlap{--}f(3)}}{\color{royalblue}{\rlap{--}f(2)}}\ \ \cdots\ \ \frac{\color{brown}{\rlap{----}f(m-1)}}{\phantom{\rlap{--}f(m-2)}}\frac{f(m)}{\color{brown}{\rlap{----}f(m-1)}}\ =\ \ f(m) $$

Indeed, one quickly verifies $\displaystyle\rm\,\ f(m) \,=\, \dfrac{(mn)!}{m!\,(n!)^{\,m}}\ \Rightarrow\ \dfrac{f(m\!+\!1)}{f(m)} \,=\, {mn\!+\!n\!-\!1\choose n\!-\!1}\in \Bbb Z\ \quad {\bf QED}$

**Remark** $\ $ Note that multiplicative telescopy reduces the proof to a trivial mechanical calculation. Absolutely no ingenuity is required. Computer algebra systems can easily construct such proofs.

If we write out the product obtained from the telescopy we obtain

$$\rm \dfrac{(mn)!}{m!\,(n!)^{\,m}}\ =\ {n\!-\!1\choose n\!-\!1}{2n\!-\!1\choose n\!-\!1} {3n\!-\!1\choose n\!-\!1}\cdots {(m\!+\!1)n\!-\!1\choose n\!-\!1}$$

This is equivalent to the product that L.F. stated since

$$\rm \frac{1}k {kn\choose n}\, =\, \frac{(kn)!}{k\, n!\, (kn\!-\!n)!} \,=\, \frac{kn (kn\!-\!1)!}{kn \,(n\!-\!1)!\, (kn\!-\!n)!} \,=\, {kn-1\choose n-1}$$